# What causes the scene outside the Death Star to change?

Tags: star-wars-tiny-death-star

I'm not sure if anyone else has noticed this, but I have not seen any commentary or questions about it:

Whatever your top level of your Death Star is, right above it if you continue to scroll, there is a small scene going on outside.

When I first began, there was a small construction droid rolling around what looked like a giant belt sander, and generating sparks.  Presumably he was polishing the metal for future construction.

Then, some time around when I built my 5th Imperial level, which I believe to have been the Turbo Laser level, the scene out there changed.  Now there are 3 droids, the original guy is welding some structure, there is another droid that looks like the mechanized suit from Avatar (and Aliens if you're as old as I am . . .) who seems to be moving a bunch of pipes around, and there is another droid crawling around some scaffolding.

Does anyone know a) what triggers these scenes to change? b) what the eventual evolution will be?  c) If anything ever happens on the bottom of your death star?

This could be a cute little easter egg if there are ever any battles taking place out there, etc.

Comment: I noticed the change from single robot to 3 robots. I had guessed it was triggered by total number of levels built, but it could just as easily be triggered by total number of imperial levels built or something else.

Comment: i believe the scene changes every 25 levels, can anyone else attest to this?

Comment: Sadly, I just built my 50th level, and no change to the scene outside. Perhaps the 51st level or the completion of construction on 50 will trigger it. But, as of now, this is a big negatory!

Comment: I think it has something to do with Imperial Inventory?<br>
I noticed that my scene up top changed when I hit 55 floors, but the Imperial Quests reset at some point, so I started using my inventory again. Then the scene up top reverted.<br>
<br>
Of course, I really won't know until I get my inventory back up :)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

As far as I can tell, it's related to the total number of floors.

- 1st change: Around 25th floor
- 2nd change: 55th floor (two flying droids and a big one)
- 3rd change: ???

And so far the bottom of the death star remains unchanged.

Comment: Can anyone else confirm that the 55th floor indeed causes a change?

Comment: I'm at 53 levels. I will probably be able to confirm this in about 2 days or so.

Comment: I thought I got it right after the 55th floor, but as it happens I got 75 bitizens almost at the same time. So it might as well be related to the number of workers.

Comment: dbernard, you are the winner.  I built my 55th level, and the scene changed immediately before my eyes.

Comment: Woohoo! Now, who's gonna be the first to get the 3rd change? ;)

Comment: I now have the current maximum of floors (82), and the outside have not changed since 55th floor. I guess we'll have to wait for new floors.

Answer (score 3):

I got the second change when I reached 35 workers.

Here is a picture of this:
[image]

Comment: So, you are sure this didn't happen at 25 levels?

Comment: And if you evict one bitizen to go back to 34, does it changed back to the initial?

Comment: Just tested that out and it stays the same as the picture even when I when went back to 34.

Comment: Negative at 75 bitizens!

Comment: I'm stumped on this one then. Maybe it is random?

Answer (score 2):

[image: Here's the new scene!]

Here it is folks.  55 Levels and these guys showed up on my TDS!

Comment: I have over 55 levels. Do not have this scene.